# spring data reactive: repository not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux

Here my error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in cat.gencat.clt.git.backend.controller.PersonController required a bean of type 'cat.gencat.clt.git.backend.repositories.PersonRepository' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'cat.gencat.clt.git.backend.repositories.PersonRepository' in your configuration.
```

My controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class PersonController {

    private final PersonRepository persons;

    @GetMapping("")
    public Flux<Person> all() {
        return this.persons.findAll();
    }
}
```

And:

```java
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Person, String> {
    
}
```

Also, I've enabled `@EnableR2dbcRepositories`.

I don't quite figure out what am i doing wrong.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
src/main/java
└── cat
    └── gencat
        └── clt
            └── git
                └── backend
                    ├── BackendApplication.java
                    ├── configuration
                    │   ├── GitConfiguration.java
                    │   ├── GitProperties.java
                    │   ├── LoginProperties.java
                    │   └── TokenProperties.java
                    ├── controller
                    │   ├── GicarController.java
                    │   └── PersonController.java
                    ├── model
                    │   └── Person.java
                    ├── repositories
                    │   └── PersonRepository.java
                    ├── SavePersonRunner.java
                    └── security
                        ├── JWTProvider.java
                        └── SecurityConfiguration.java
```

Comment: How does your package structure look like?

Comment: Your PersonRepository isn't scanned by Spring. What type of Spring project is it? SpringBoot? Is there any specific scanning configuration (ComponentScan annotation) ? What is the structure of your project?

Comment: I've added project structure. There is not specific `ComponentScan` annotation.

Comment: Is your backend application a SpringBoot application?

Comment: What is the class with the @EnableR2dbcRepositories annotation? Did you specify a  base package in the annotation? `@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackage="cat.gencat.clt.git.backend.repositories")`

Comment: Yes, it's a spring boot application.

Comment: can you please produce a small reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

In your `PersonRepository` interface, extend `R2dbcRepository` instead of `ReactiveCrudRepository` I don't know the reason but I had the same issue and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used @SpringBootApplication annotaion in your main file i.e. BackendApplication.java? Note that this annotaion has the feature of @ComponentScan which scans the packages for creating the beans which are to be managed by spring(spring's ioc container)

Can you check/share the file BackendApplication.java